# jsPlumbBrowserUI.getInstance is not a function

Tags: angular, jsplumb

I'm trying to setup @jsplumb/browser-ui in my angular project as per the documentation https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/ . But, i'm not able to access the getInstance method.

```
import * as jsPlumbBrowserUI from '@jsplumb/browser-ui';

const instance = jsPlumbBrowserUI.getInstance({
      container: this.wrapper
  })
```

How do i integrate this in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no getInstance function, you might use `newInstance`:

```
const instance = jsPlumbBrowserUI.newInstance({
      container: this.wrapper
  })
```

Comment: The doc is outdated though. Do you have any demo or doc i can refer for the same?

Comment: I too could not get the info from their doc, then I looked at their code itself and found they are exporting new instance . Explore their codebase to get more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the latest docs. They've been updated now to show `newInstance` and not `getInstance`.

Various demonstrations for version 5.0 can be found here:

https://github.com/jsplumb-demonstrations